# How to change option allowInsecureConnection Node.Js working with Azurite

Tags: node.js, azurite, azure-tableclient

I try to connect to a Table in Azurite from an azure function written in node.js

```
myTableClient = TableClient.fromConnectionString(process.env.STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING,
"myTable" );   
entity = await myTableClient.getEntity("partitionkey", "rowkey");
```

I am getting

> Cannot connect to
> [http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1/myTable(PartitionKey='partitionkey',RowKey='rowkey')](http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1/myTable(PartitionKey=%27partitionkey%27,RowKey=%27rowkey%27))
> while **allowInsecureConnection** is false.

I understand there is a difference connecting to Azure and to Azurite (which is by default over Http but not Https)
How can I change this setting allowInsecureConnection so the code can work with Azurite for testing purposes?

I see there is 3rd parameter in constrtuctor of the TableClient , called TableServiceClientOptions but I cannot see in documentation how it can be used to manipulate allowInsecureConnection setting for Azurite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decision was found and is fairly simple

```
myTableClient = TableClient.fromConnectionString(process.env.STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING, "myTable", { allowInsecureConnection: true } );
```